# Call an API with python

Tags: json, python-3.x, api, python-requests, language-translation

I used Postman to get a bit more info and have used the snippet of code to run the request it is working now but i still want the request to print in JSON not in text im really stuck.....

```
    import requests

url = "https://ice3x.com/api/v1/stats/marketdepthfull/"

headers = {
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "afb97efe-aaf1-cdae-004f-29aac565780a"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

The result i get is:-
{"errors":false,"response":{"entities":[{"pair_id":"3","min":"56600.00000000","max":"59600.00000000","avg":"58547.48550813","vol":"5.68526617","pair_name":"btc/zar","last_price":"58547.00000000"},{"pair_id":"4","min":"0.00000000","max":"0.00000000","avg":"0.00000000","vol":"0.00000000","pair_name":"btc/ngn","last_price":"1560000.00000000"},{"pair_id":"6","min":"732.00000000","max":"781.00000000","avg":"765.97099358","vol":"160.77519562","pair_name":"ltc/zar","last_price":"760.00000000"},{"pair_id":"11","min":"4050.00000000","max":"4349.00000000","avg":"4253.33493584","vol":"74.22964491","pair_name":"eth/zar","last_price":"4230.00000000"},{"pair_id":"12","min":"0.00000000","max":"0.00000000","avg":"0.00000000","vol":"0.00000000","pair_name":"eth/ngn","last_price":"110000.00000000"}]},"pagination":{"items_per_page":1000,"total_items":5,"current_page":1,"total_pages":1}}

Process finished with exit code 0

What i need is to be able to dump the json and call it again if i need it
Please help

Comment: You are making two different requests, but only looking at the response from the request inside your class (which appears to be the wrong one). Take a look at `response`.

Comment: What is the error message that you are seeing? Post the error/warning messages